# MongoDB findOneAndUpdate projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, projection

I'm currently using MongoDB and using the `findOneAndUpdate` method. I'm trying to use the projection however it doesn't seem to be working 100% successfully.

Here is the projection:

```
{
  orderID: '$_id',
  _id: false,
  user: true,
  guild: true,
  order: true,
  status: true,
  orderExpiry: true,
  priority: true,
  sentAt: true
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set `orderID` to the value of `_id` however, it doesn't do anything.

Here is the code I am executing for reference :

```js
await this.db.collection('orders').findOneAndUpdate(filter, { $set: { ...data } },
                  { returnOriginal: false, projection: this.getProjectionFields() });
```

I hope someone can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know projection with `.find()` or similar `.findOneAndUpdate()` does not support field transformations(adding new field out of existing) which `$project` in aggregation is capable of doing. So projection can be used just to include or exclude certain fields from result. Although this is true but up-to certain extent this is false, we can transform an array field using projection operators, Check : [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#find-projection).